# modifying a new window using Javascript contained in the parent page

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way by which a user can click on a link in a webpage, which would then trigger a new window being opened up,  **which is then populated with content** by javascript from the original page?

I need to write a self contained HTML file (so cannot use external links) that is able to BUILD a new window with predefined content...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. JavaScript's `window.open` method should be used for opening a new window.

That method returns back an object corresponding to a new window, so your JavaScript code can now access new window's DOM objects using that object.

See [this](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/javascript/popupwindows.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can open a new window ([`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)) and write the content of the inner document stream programmatically, using [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.write).

```
function example () {
  var newWindow = window.open('about:blank','name','height=400,width=500');

  newWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Test</title>');
  newWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
  newWindow.document.write('<p>Test page generated programmatically.</p>');
  newWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
  newWindow.document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of writing  content to a child window:

```
child_window = window.open('', 'name', 'width=300,height=300');
child_window.document.write('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
```